# Append javascript functions and vars declaration to an object from a string

Tags: javascript, class, web

I'm facing the following problem:

I have a string which contains javascript vars and functions declarations.

Example:

```
// this is the content of the jsString var passed to the _MyClass ctor
var toto = "Hey";
var foo ="oh";
function myFunc(str) {
    toto = str;
}
```

And I have a class declared like this:

```
class _MyClass
{
    constructor(jsString) // where JsString is the above JS 
    {
        this.aVar = 2;
    }
}
```

And I would like to populate my **_MyClass** class with the JS string.
I need to be able to call:

```
var myClassInstance = new _MyClass(jsString);
myClassInstance.myFunc("test");
```

I know this is possible to populate the window object with the **eval** func, but I don't know if it's possible for an object (eval func on object is deprecated).

I also know that is not common, but it is used in a particular context where I haven't the choice.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? What does the string parameter in `_MyClass`'s ctor do? Are you simply trying to set a global variable from an instance method, or are you trying to set an instance variable?

Comment: Why would you need to have code in a string like that?! (Not my dv)

Comment: I know this is not a common practice, but I haven't the choice. the string passed to my ctor is the JS example at the begining of my post "var toto = "Hey";....."

Comment: @Akiat: ***Why*** don't you have a choice?

Comment: Because I need to emulate an environment.

Comment: That still just begs the question of what kind of environment you would need to emulate to have a requirement like this. But since you're apparently not going to answer the question, I won't ask it. :-) I can only think of one use case: Something similar to a browser console or Node REPL. But anyway...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requirement is bizarre and I would strongly recommend that you do whatever you possibly can to get rid of the requirement in favor of passing *data* into your constructor, not a string containing code.

But for the requirement itself: Unless you know the names of the variables and functions in the string in advance, you cannot do this without a JavaScript parser (such as [Esprima](http://esprima.org) — that link is down right now, but I assume it's temporary).

Using Esprima or something like it, you'd:

1. Parse the code.
2. Use information from the parsing data (line and character, etc.) to modify the code string, changing `var toto = ...` to `obj.toto = ...` and `function myFunc()...` to `obj.myFunc = function myFunc()...` and such (being aware of and careful about losing the hoisting, since we're changing function declarations into function expressions). You'll also have to find and update references to the identifiers within the functions (which you can do with Esprima, and presumably with others).
3. Then in the constructor:

   ```
   var obj = this;
   eval(theUpdatedCode);
   ```

   ...to evaluate the code in the current context. That would assign the various things to `obj`.

Again, I **would not do that**, I'd do my best to change the requirement instead.